# JQuery/javascript: Is it possible do this (watch link below) with simple image on webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

http://testmenow.500mb.net

So, as you can see, i can change hue/saturation and other effects, but it's possible only with html elements, what if I to do this with JPG,JPEG,PNG or other formats images placed on my page, what I need to do, need a feature convertor or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out some [JavaScript image manipulation](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20image%20manipulation) libraries, such as [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/).

There is even an article mentioning 10 of them: http://www.blogohblog.com/top-10-javascripts-for-image-manipulation/